# I can't get the result of a Generic List query

Tags: c#, linq, generic-list

```
public class UTCTime
{
    public DateTime UTCBas { get; set; }
    public DateTime UTCSon { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Fark { get; set; }
    public char Sezon { get; set; }

    public UTCTime(string UTCStart , string UTCStop , string Fark , char Sezon)
    {
        this.UTCBas = Convert.ToDateTime(UTCStart);
        this.UTCBas = Convert.ToDateTime(UTCStop);
        this.Fark = TimeSpan.Parse(Fark);
        this.Sezon = Sezon;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{this.UTCBas.ToString(@"yyy-MM-dd")} - {this.UTCBas.ToString(@"yyy-MM-dd")} - {this.Fark} - {this.Sezon}";
    }
}
```

I'm entering this data into the Generic List from this class.

```
public static void MTDoldur()
{
    MarketTime.Add(new UTCTime("2000-04-01", "2000-10-28", "03:00", 'Y'));
    MarketTime.Add(new UTCTime("2000-10-28", "2001-03-31", "02:00", 'K'));
    MarketTime.Add(new UTCTime("2001-03-31", "2001-10-27", "03:00", 'Y'));
    MarketTime.Add(new UTCTime("2001-10-27", "2002-04-06", "02:00", 'K'));
    MarketTime.Add(new UTCTime("2002-04-06", "2002-10-26", "03:00", 'Y'));
    MarketTime.Add(new UTCTime("2002-10-26", "2003-04-05", "02:00", 'K'));
    MarketTime.Add(new UTCTime("2003-04-05", "2003-10-25", "03:00", 'Y'));
    MarketTime.Add(new UTCTime("2003-10-25", "2004-04-03", "02:00", 'K'));
}
```

I want to add the result of the LINQ Query into the Generic List that will be created from this clas.

```
public class SonucTime
{
    public TimeSpan Fark { get; set; }
    public char Sezon { get; set; }

    public SonucTime(TimeSpan Fark , char Sezon)
    {
        this.Fark = Fark;
        this.Sezon = Sezon;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Fark : {this.Fark}   Sezon : {this.Sezon}";
    }
}
```

I'm pulling the query type in the VAR data type does not fail, but I can't print the data on the screen and assign it to variables.
I want to transfer the result to Generic List and export the data to variables from the VAR Data type.
I can't figure out my problem, I'm waiting for your help.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MTDoldur();

    DateTime xT = new DateTime();
    xT = new DateTime(2003, 12, 21);

    var sonuc = (from m in MarketTime 
                 where xT >= m.UTCBas && xT <= m.UTCSon
                 select new { m.Fark, m.Sezon }).ToList(); 
}
```

Comment: `new { m.Fark, m.Sezon }` creates an anonymous type, which I don't think it what you want. I think you want to create an instance of `SonucTime`. That would be `new SonucTime(m.Fark, m.Sezon)`. Anonymous types are like temporary types that we can't pass around, which is why you can't pass the results to another method. If your query selects `new SonucTime` the result is `IEnumerable<SonucTime>`, and then if you add `ToList()` you get `List<SonucTime>`.

Comment: @ScottHannen  Thank you for your comment.
Can you show me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made the 'copy-past'-error in UTCTime-constructor - the *UTCSon* was not initialized.

Need to fix constructor:

```
public UTCTime(string UTCStart , string UTCStop , string Fark , char Sezon)
{
    this.UTCBas = Convert.ToDateTime(UTCStart);
    this.UTCSon = Convert.ToDateTime(UTCStop); // <----
    this.Fark = TimeSpan.Parse(Fark);
    this.Sezon = Sezon;
}
```

and request data:

```
var sonuc = (from m in MarketTime 
            where xT >= m.UTCBas && xT <= m.UTCSon
            select new SonucTime(m.Fark, m.Sezon))
            .ToList();
/*
result:
sonuc
Count = 1
[0] [SonucTime]:{Fark : 02:00:00   Sezon : K}
Fark [TimeSpan]:{02:00:00}
Sezon [char]:75 'K'
*/
```

Comment: Thank you very much for providing my solution.
Using this directly provides better performance?
or
Sending the result to the Generic List instead of the VAR type is more efficient.
The record count will make billions of queries.